# Tree grid expand/collapse in Extjs6.2 collapse does not work

Tags: extjs6-classic, extjs-grid

Am using Extjs6.2 . I have used extjs tree panel. Following is my code for the same:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    scrollable: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    collapsed: false,
    title: 'My Panel',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'treepanel',
        height: 370,
        id: 'id_treegrid',
        itemId: 'id_treegrid',
        scrollable: true,
        title: 'My Tree Panel',
        reserveScrollbar: true,
        store: 'MyTreeStore',
        singleExpand: true,
        useArrows: true,
        viewConfig: {
            rootVisible: false
        },
        columns: [{
            xtype: 'treecolumn',
            dataIndex: 'description',
            text: 'MyTreeColumn'
        }, {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'successCount',
            text: 'Success'
        }, {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'totalCDRCount',
            text: 'Attempts'
        }, {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'failedCount',
            text: 'Failed'
        }, {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'cdrTimeoutCount',
            text: 'Timeout'
        }],
        listeners: {
            expand: 'onId_treegridExpand',
            collapse: 'onId_treegridCollapse'
        }
    }],
    listeners: {
        activate: 'onPanelActivate'
    }
}
```

After this code following is my grid coming. It has total four rows. [image]

When we expand first row of grid it looks like following. It will expand with all other child rows and other[ parent three rows ]in bottom :
[image]

and when I collapse the first row, it will have only one row. all below three rows goes away as seen in below picture. [image]

I don't know what mistake I did. How do I solve this or debug this issue? I don't get any error on web console as well.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Can you provide link for sencha fiddle?

Comment: Hi,
it works with fiddle. I have tried but when I develop it in my sencha architect , it is having this strange behaviour.